catch multiple exceptions from initializer list
If I initialize member fields inside the body of the constructor, I can catch separately the exceptions by surrounding each variable initialization by a try-catch block. For example:
#include <memory>

struct A {
   std::unique_ptr<int[]> data1, data2;
   A();
};

A::A()
{
   try {
       data1 = new int[5];
   }
   catch (std::bad_alloc& ex) {
       /* Do something */
   }
   try {
       data2 = new int[5];
   }
   catch (std::bad_alloc& ex) {
       /* Do something */
   }
}

In the code I may want to do something different when the allocation of data1 or data2 fails.
Now, what about initializing data1 and data2 directly in the initializer list? I can still catch bad_alloc as discussed here and here:
#include <memory>

struct A {
   std::unique_ptr<int[]> data1, data2;
   A();
};

A::A()
try : data1{new int[5]},
      data2{new int[5]}
{
}
catch (std::bad_alloc& ex) {
       /* Do something */
}

Doing so, however, I would not know, when catching bad_alloc if this was raised by the new statement for data1, or for data2.
I could differentiate if, say, the initialization of data1 and data2 would throw different exceptions; this is not the case here.
How can I distinguish the possible exceptions raised in the initializers list?

Wrap your news in member functions, and have those member functions catch exceptions. Call them from the member-init-list.

Or wrap the in immediately-executed lambda's. I.e. [ ]( ){ throw 42; ]( ).

Try to wrap your news in member functions. Catch exceptions within those functions, act accordingly.
#include <memory>

struct A {
   std::unique_ptr<int[]> data1, data2;
   A();

   private:
       std::unique_ptr<int[]> wrap_data1();
       std::unique_ptr<int[]> wrap_data2();
};

std::unique_ptr<int[]> A::wrap_data1() {
    try {
        return std::make_unique<int[]>(5);
    } 
    catch (std::bad_alloc& ex) {
        std::cout << "Allocation for data1 failed: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
        throw;
    }
}

std::unique_ptr<int[]> A::wrap_data2() {
    try {
        return std::make_unique<int[]>(5);
    } 
    catch (std::bad_alloc& ex) {
        std::cout << "Allocation for data2 failed: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
        throw;
    }
}

A::A()
try : data1{wrap_data1()},
      data2{wrap_data2()}
{
}
catch (std::bad_alloc& ex) {
       /* Do something */
}

